# Mod_Redirect Find Keywords

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know this had to have been asked before but it seems my search has come up void and everything I'm trying isn't working.

I'm trying to find urls that have the key word js or php in them and redirect to a different page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ajson/(.*)/[js|php]/(.*)$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/[js|php]/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/       /ajson/test4.php?u5u=$1&f5f=$3&o5o=$2 [QSA,L]
```

One I cannot get it to direct to test4.php at all and also I want to know which key word was placed in the url js or php.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For using regex alternation you need to use:

```
(js|php)
```

instead of

```
[js|php]
```

which is a character class.

Full rule:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/(?:js|php)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /ajson/test4.php?u5u=$1&f5f=$4&e5e=$3&o5o=$2 [QSA,L]
```

where `(?:..)` is called non-capturing group.

Comment: yes tried that too, doesn't seem to be directing to test4.php still

Comment: What is the original URL you are trying to rewrite and are there more rules in this htaccess?

Comment: there are more rules, I've placed this rule at the top an example url would be {domain}/ajson/wattsjus/js/AddThreeNumbs

Comment: Your question has very little info. I shouldn't need to keep asking these questions in comments. How should `/ajson/wattsjus/js/AddThreeNumbs` be rewritten to and what are other rules?